# Approximating a function of bounded variation function by a stepfunction obtained by averaging over measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, bounded-variation

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062470/l1-approximation-of-bv-functions-by-piecewise-constant-function) question, suppose that we have a function $f\in\mathrm{BV}([0,1])\cap L^1([0,1])$, take a measurable partition $\mathcal P^N$ of $[0,1]=\bigcup_{i=1}^NI_i$, and obtain a new function $f^N$ obtained by averaging over the sets $I_i$: when $x\in I_i$, $$f^N(x)=\frac1{|I_i|}\int_{I_i}f(y)\ \mathrm dy.$$ As in the linked question, we have $f^N\in L^1[0,1]$, and if the mesh of the partition tends to $0$ when $N\to\infty$, we can argue that $f^N\to f$ a.e. as $N\to\infty$.

I was wondering whether it is possible in this case to prove that $$\|f^N-f\|_{L^1[0,1]}\leq\|f\|_{TV}\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^N),$$ though the approach of the linked question didn't seem to work here directly. I hope someone can help.

EDIT: as Alex Ravsky's counterexample shows, we cannot just take $\mathcal P^N$ to be *any* measurable partition. Instead, let's assume that we have partitions of the form $0=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_{n-1}<t_n=1$ of the unit interval in disjoint, consecutive intervals $[t_{k-1}, t_k)$. In this case, I'm still wondering if the result holds. A similar bound is not hard to prove if we assume that the size of the smallest and largest set in the $N$th partition do not differ by more than a factor $C$, independent of $N$. However, I'm particularly interested in *not* making that assumption.

Comment: What is $\|f\|_{TV}$?

Comment: And what is $\operatorname{mesh}(\mathcal P^N)$ when the members of the partition  $\mathcal P^N$ are not necessarily segments of intervals? The maximum of measures of the members of  $\mathcal P^N$ or the maximum of their diameters?

Comment: $\|\cdot\|$ is the total variational norm, while I'm willing to assume that the partition consist of intervals, if necessary; in the general case, it would be the maximum of their measures.

Comment: I expect some restrictions are necessary because of the following example. 
I hope the calculations below are correct, despite that I did not check all details.

We deal with $[0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$
Put $f(x)=2x$ for each $x\in [0,1)$. For each natural $N\ge 2$ and each $i\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ put $I_i=\bigcup_{j=0}^{N-1} \left[\tfrac{jN+i-1}{N^2},\tfrac{jN+i}{N^2}\right)$.

Comment: If $x\in I_i$ then
$$f^N(x)=\frac1{|I_i|}\int_{I_i}f(y)\ \mathrm dy=$$
$$N\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\int_{\frac{jN+i-1}{N^2}}^{\frac{jN+i}{N^2}} 2y\ \mathrm dy=$$
$$N\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\left(\left(\frac{jN+i}{N^2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{jN+i-1}{N^2}\right)^2\right)=$$
$$\frac 1{N^3}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}\left(2jN+2i-1\right)=$$ $$\frac{N^2(N-1)+(2i-1)N}{N^3}=$$ $$1+\frac{2i-N-1}{N^2}.$$

Thus $f^N(x)=1+O\left(\tfrac 1N\right)$, which implies
$$\|f^N-f\|_{L^1[0,1]}=$$
$$\int_0^1|1-f(x)|\ \mathrm dx+O\left(\frac 1N\right)=$$ $$\frac 12+O\left(\frac 1N\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for your input! This makes sense, I just made an edit introducing more restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again, I hope the calculations below are correct, althoug that I did not check all details. I am going do this later.

Let $[f]=\{g:[0,1]:\to\mathbb R: g=f \mbox{ almost everywhere on} [0,1]\}$.

Let $g\in [f]$ be any function.

Then $g^N(x)=f^N(x)$ for any $x\in [0,1]$.

Moreover, if $x\in I_i$ then $\inf_{x'\in I_i} g(x')\le g^N(x)\le \sup_{x''\in I_i} g(x'')$.

It follows that $|g^N(x)-g(x)|\le \Delta_i$, where $\Delta_i=\sup_{x',x''\in I_i}|g(x'')-g(x')|$.

Next, $\sum_{i=1}^{N}\Delta_i\le\operatorname{var} g,$ where
$$\operatorname{var} g=\sup\{\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} |g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i)|: 0=x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_N=1\}.$$

Then we obtain that
$$\|f^N-f\|_{L[0,1]}=\int_{[0,1]}|f^N(x)-f(x)|\mathrm dx=$$
$$\int_{[0,1]}|g^N(x)-g(x)|\mathrm dx=\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{I_i}|g^N(x)-g(x)|\mathrm dx\le $$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int_{I_i}\Delta_i\mathrm dx=\sum_{i=1}^{N}|I_i|\Delta_i\le \sum_{i=1}^{N}\operatorname{mesh}(\mathcal P^N)\Delta_i\le$$
$$\operatorname{mesh}(\mathcal P^N)\operatorname{var}{g}.$$

Thus if $\|f\|_{TV}=\inf_{g\in [f]} \operatorname{var} g$ then $\|f^N-f\|_{L[0,1]}\le \operatorname{mesh}(\mathcal P^N) \|f\|_{TV}.$