# Bounding $L^1$ norm of the difference between a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ of bounded variation and a piecewise constant approximation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, geometric-measure-theory, bounded-variation

As a follow up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765614/approximating-a-function-of-bounded-variation-function-by-a-stepfunction-obtaine) question, which deals with univariate functions, I assume that we are given a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ which is of bounded variation on bounded sets, meaning, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_n_%3E_1_real_variables), that for $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ open and bounded
$$V(f,\Omega)=\sup\left\{\int_\Omega f(x)\mathrm{div}\phi(x)\ \mathrm dx:\phi\in C_c^1(\Omega,\mathbb R^n),\|\phi\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq1\right\}$$
is finite.
I want to take some bounded set $A\subset\mathbb R^n$; I'm willing to assume that $A$ is an hyperrectangle, i.e. $A$ is of the form $A=\prod_{i=1}^n[a_i,b_i)$. Then we partition $A$ into $d$ hyperrectangles $A_1^d,\ldots,A_d^d$, and we denote this partition by $\mathcal P^d$. We define its mesh by the largest Lebesgue measure (EDIT: **it seems that we need to define the mesh as the largest diameter**, see @dsh's comment and second update to their answer) among the elements from this partition. Then the piecewise constant function $f^d$ is obtained by averaging over the elements of the partition, i.e. with $|A_i^d|$ the Lebesgue measure of $A_i^d$  $$f^d|_{A_i^d}=\frac1{|A_i^d|}\int_{A_i^d}f(x)\ \mathrm dx.$$

Similarly to the univariate case, I was wondering whether we can prove that $$\|f^d-f\|_{L^1(A)}\leq V(f,A)\cdot \mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d).$$

Since my multivariate calculus is not that strong, I'm having some difficulty proving this. I'm wondering whether this can be done similarly as in the univariate case, as done by Alex Ravsky in the linked question. Intuitively, the answer should definitely be yes, but I was wondering how to bound $\Delta_i:=\sup_{x\in A_i^d}f(x)-\inf_{x\in A_i^d}f(x)$ by the integrand involving the divergence operator. More specifically, ignoring the fact that we should deal with equivalence classes for the moment, some easy bounding gives
\begin{align*}
\|f^d-f\|_{L^1(A)}&=\int_A|f^d(x)-f(x)|\ \mathrm dx=\sum_{i=1}^d\int_{A_i}|f^d(x)-f(x)|\ \mathrm dx\leq\sum_{i=1}^d\int_{A_i}\Delta_i\ \mathrm dx\\
&\leq\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)\sum_{i=1}^d\Delta_i,
\end{align*} so that it suffices to prove that for any partition $\mathcal P^d$ of (the hyperrectangle) $A$ into $d$ subsets (hyperrectangles) $A_i$ it holds that $$\sum_{i=1}^d\Delta_i\leq V(f,A).$$

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check $f = x_1$ (dependence on single variable) and partition $(\mathcal P^d)$ that does not touch first coordinate? It looks like left hand side is constant for all such partitions and does not converge to 0. It seems like a mesh should be small in all directions...

Comment: Thank you again, I didn't think about that, but I'm willing to assume that the maximum diameter of elements of the partition tends to $0$. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer. [Longer article on bounded variation functions](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Function_of_bounded_variation) contains [Poincaré inequality](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Function_of_bounded_variation#Poincar.C3.A9_inequality):
$$\|f|A^d_i − f^d|A^d_i\|_{L^{1∗}(A^d_i)} \le C_2 \|Df\|(\mathrm{int}(A^d_i))$$ where $1^* = n/(n-1)$ and $\|Df\|$ is a finite positive measure associated with $f.$ $\|Df\|(\Omega) = V(f, \Omega).$ This inequality is used for $n=1 (1^* = \infty, C_2 = 1)$ in the linked question. [Holder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) and Poincaré inequality give result up to constant.

**UPD 1.**
In Holder inequality use $p=1^*$ and $q=n$ with $f =f|A^d_i − f^d|A^d_i, g = \chi_{A^d_i}.$

**UPD 2.** Consider $f=x_1+\ldots+x_n.$ Then $\|Df\|$ is Lebesgue measure $dx$ up to *constant* depending on $n.$ General formula is
$$
\int_U f\mathrm{div}\phi\:dx = - \int_U (\phi, \sigma)\:d\|Df\|
$$
where $|\sigma|_2 = 1,$ $\sigma$ is vector function with $\|Df\|$-almost everywhere (from [EG] p.195, see link to encyclopediaofmath.org).
This is generalization of integration by parts, so for particular $f$ $\sigma = \nabla f/|\nabla f|_2 = (1, \ldots, 1)/\sqrt{n},$ $\|Df\| = \sqrt{n}\:dx$

Consider $A^d_i$ with all sizes equal to $\delta$ then
$ c\delta^{n+1} \le \|f|A^d_i − f^d|A^d_i\|_{L^1(A^d_i)} \le C\delta^{n+1}$ where $c, C > 0$ constants depending on n. On the other  hand $\|Df\|(A^d_i) = \sqrt{n}\delta^n.$ Summing up for $i$ one obtains
$$
 c'\delta \le \|f − f^d\|_{L^1}/V(f, A) \le C'\delta
$$
where $\delta = \sqrt[n]{A^d_i}.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am really looking for a bound involving $\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)$ as well. It seems that Poincaré's inequality only holds for $n\geq2$, so $n=1$ does not seem feasible. If I apply Hölder, as you suggest, I end up with a bound involving $\sqrt{|A_i^d|}$. Does Poincaré's inequality hold as well for $n=1$?

If I apply Holder as you suggest for $n=2$, I end up with

Comment: @václav-mordvinov. It looks to me that the answer in the linked question essentially proves the case $n=1$ with $L^{1^*}=L^\infty$ for the intervals. I think $\max \sqrt[n]{|A_i^d|} \le C\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)$

Comment: What do you refer to by `linked question'? Do you mean https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4765614/approximating-a-function-of-bounded-variation-function-by-a-stepfunction-obtaine?

Comment: For the application I have in mind, I will consider a situation in which $\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)\to0$ as $d\to\infty$, so this might become problematic. In particular, such a constant $C$ would itself depend on the partition. I'd need the constant to be independent of $d$.

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Yes, I mean the link from the question. Using notations from the answer $\max_{x\in I_i}|g^N(x)-g(x)|\le \Delta_i$ for $n=1$, note that $\Delta_i = \|Df\|(I_i).$

Comment: I understand that this holds from $n=1$, but I don't see how your answer implies a bound involving $\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)$ (instead of the $\sqrt{\cdot}$) for general $n>1$

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov It looks, I used definition of mesh from initial version of question as max diameter.

Comment: My apologies for my confusing comments, I was thinking that $n$ was just some number we could choose, but of course it is just the dimension that I fixed. However, for general $n$ we end up with a bound in terms of $\sqrt[n]{|A_i^d|}$ instead of just $|A_i^d|$, so probably I'm looking for a different approach than yours. Thanks for your time anyways

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov It looks like you need to obtain $L^\infty$ estimation instead of $L^{1^*}$ for $\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)$ as $\max|A^d_i|.$
Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality#Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Wirtinger_inequality will be useful.

Comment: Your bound applies to each element of the partition, so each time we could just bound $|A_i^d|$ by $\max|A_i^d|$. In the Poincaré-Wirtinger inequality, C still depends on $\Omega$, and the inequality does not seem to yield the type of inequality I'm looking for

Comment: Thank you again for your update. When you say 'Consider $A_i^d$ with all *sizes* equal to $\delta$', does `size' mean the Lebesgue measure of those sets?

Comment: So if I understand it correctly: your second update shows that my conjecture is false if we define the mesh of the partition as the largest Lebesgue measure. However, in your second update, $A_i^d$ are squares with edge length $\delta$, so diameter $\sqrt n\delta$, so that $\|f-f^d\|_{L^1}$ can in fact be bounded by $V(f,A)\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)$, *if we define the mesh as the largest diameter* (for this particular choice of $f$)

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov There is still have only estimation up to constant, but order of convergence related to mesh is not smaller than $\sqrt[n]{A^d_i}.$ It looks like it is closely related to approximation of continuously differentiable function with linear function (no better approximation in general). It is interesting whether exact constant for continuously differentiable functions and general functions of bounded variation is the same.

Comment: In your example, $\delta$ is equal to the diameter of the $A_i^d$'s, up to a constant depending on $n$. I'm still very interested in whether a bound $\|f^d-f\|_{L^1(A)}\leq V(f,A)\cdot \mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)$ holds with $\mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d)=\max_{i\in[d]}\mathrm{diam}(A_i^d)$

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Agree, $$\sup_{f\in BV(A), V(f,A) \neq 0}\|f^d-f\|_{L^1(A)}/(V(f,A)\cdot \mathrm{mesh}(\mathcal P^d))$$ still needs to be computed to remove "partial answer")

Answer (score 2):

I may have found a solution to this problem in the literature. I could use some feedback, though. Please let me know if you think this approach is valid.

It seems that my conjecture is correct for functions in $W^{1,1}$; the proof being an immediate corollary of Theorem 3.2 of [*An optimal Poincaré inequality in $L^1$ for convex domains*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-01/S0002-9939-03-07004-7/S0002-9939-03-07004-7.pdf) by Acosta and Durán:

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a convex domain with diameter $d$ and $u\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ such that $\int_\Omega u=0$. Then $$\|u\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\leq\frac12d\|\nabla u\|_{L^1(\Omega)}.$$

The result then follows from [Theorem 2 on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#The_form_of_the_total_variation_of_a_differentiable_function_of_several_variables) or $\S$13.2 from Leoni's textbook on Sobolev spaces, using $u=f-\frac1\Omega\int_\Omega f$, defined on $\Omega$. It seems possible to carry over this result to any function of bounded variation on $\Omega$, using an approach like the one from Theorem 1, $\S$5.6.1, p. 189 of the [Evans & Gariepy textbook](https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/MATH811/Evans%20L.C.%2C%20Gariepy%20R.F.%20-%20Measure%20theory%20and%20fine%20properties%20of%20functions-CRC%20%281992%29%20%282%29.pdf). Using Theorem 2 from $\S$5.2.2 of the same textbook, we select a sequence $(u_k)\subset C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ converging to $u$ in $L^1(\Omega)$,
and such that ($\|\nabla u_k\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$)=$\|D u_k\|\to\|Du\|=V(u,\Omega)$. Then by Fatou's lemma and the stated result for $W^{1,1}$ functions,
\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\leq\liminf_{k\to\infty}\|u_k\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac12d\|\nabla u_k\|_{L^1(\Omega)}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac12d\|Du_k\|=\frac12d\|Du\|.
\end{align*}